# Service - the service isn't stopping

Tags: android, service

I'm having some problems with services.

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

private static final String TAG = "AutoService";
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask task;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Auto Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
    int period = 5000; // repeat every sec.

    timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }, delay, period);


}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    timer.cancel();
    task.cancel();
    return super.stopService(name);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class ClientSocket extends ActionBarActivity {

CheckBox enablecheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_socket);

    enablecheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.enablecheck);

    enablecheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(enablecheck.isChecked()){
                startService(new Intent(ClientSocket.this, MyService.class));
            }else
            {
                stopService(new Intent(ClientSocket.this, MyService.class));

            }
        }

    });
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ClientSocket"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>
```

I'm just testing, when I try to stop the service, the fuction onDestroy() is called but don't stop the service. The service/android:exported and android:enable both are true.

Any help?

Comment: can you place your manifest ?

Comment: How do you assert that the service is not stopped?

Comment: @quanturium The program is still print "done" on the Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Timer` instance create a background thread. If you want to stop the service completely you also need to stop the thread. Timer has a `cancel()` method you can call in the onDestroy() method to terminate the Timer.

Also, exporting the service means other applications (processes) can access it. You most likely don't need that.

Comment: @quanturim Thanks, I thought that the cancel() on the stopService() would work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the code is a misunderstanding of what

```
@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    timer.cancel();
    task.cancel();
    return super.stopService(name);

}
```

really does.

It is not a callback that is called when the service is stopped. Instead it is overriding the `stopService` method on `Context`, which you *call* to stop a service (as you do in the Activity in your example).

In fact the override of `stopService`in your code has no effect at all.

```
timer.cancel();
task.cancel();
```

should be placed in the `onDestroy` method of your service.